# Can anyone recommend any good UK based SMS gateways for sending and receiving SMS using C#?

Tags: c#, sms-gateway

Has anyone used any in the UK, and if so, were they any good?

Comment: You might want to add a definition for **Good**. What is good for you? The cheapest? The most performant? The easiest to interface with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/products/sms%5Fgateway.php) is a popular SMS gateway. It works in 200+ countries.

Their API offers a choice of connection options via: HTTP/S, SMPP, SMTP, FTP, XML, SOAP, COM Object.

The HTTP/S method is as simple as this: `http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?to=NUMBER&msg=Message+Body+Here` ([Clickatell API Guide](http://support.clickatell.com/guides/clickatell/api_guide.php)).

The SMTP method consists of sending a plain-text e-mail to: `sms@messaging.clickatell.com`, with the following body:

```
user: xxxxx
password: xxxxx
api_id: xxxxx
to: 448311234567
text: Meet me at home
```

As for incoming SMSes, you would have to expose an interface through: HTTP, SMPP, SOAP or FTP. For example if you use the HTTP GET and you provide this URL to Clickatell: `http://www.yourdomain.com/sms/sms.asp`, then Clickatell will send you this HTTP GET with every incoming SMS:

```
https://www.yourdomain.com/sms/sms.asp?
   api_id=12345&
   from=279991235642&
   to=27123456789&
   timestamp=2008-08-0609:43:50&
   text=Hereisthe%20messagetext&
   charset=ISO-8859-1&
   moMsgId=b2aee337abd962489b123fda9c3480fa
```

You can also test the gateway (incoming and outgoing) for free from your browser: "[Test SMS Gateway](http://www.clickatell.com/products/test_gateway.php)".

Comment: That sounds easy! How do you receive SMS?

Comment: You may want to check the 2-Way Technical Guide: http://www.clickatell.com/downloads/Clickatell_two-way_technical_guide.pdf. You would have to expose an interface through: HTTP GET, HTTP POST, SMPP, XML GET, XML POST, FTP, SOAP GET, SOAP POST. You will also be able to see incoming SMSes from the back-end interface.

Answer (score 1):

TM4B offer an easy-to-use web-based API, but there are some limitations to what kind of content it can be used for (nothing to do with music, gambling, drinking), BulkSMS is also quite highly regarded and, once again, offer a very simple web-based API.

I've used both before (we have an SMS provider abstraction library create in-house) and both are as reliable as the underlying transport (SMS is not a guaranteed communication method, so messages can go astray).

Answer (score 1):

We use [AQL](http://aql.com/?gclid=COHA4uqd1p4CFVmX2AodBylisA). They arent the cheapest but never had a single issue. We only use for outgoing however so I cant speak for inbound. Simple to use in .NET. Great web interface too.