# sms gateway so I can send a text to a server and get back a response?

Tags: mobile, sms, sms-gateway

I am wanting to setup a service that allows people to send a text to my server and have the server return results of their questions.

Let's say they send a text to my server saying "movies"

and it returns the results

"Boondock Saints"

"Avatar"

"Star Trek - Spock got lost again"

what is this called?
how much would something like this cost?
would you be able to point me to a company that already offers this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you google "inbound sms gateway" or "virtual sms" a large number of companies offering such SMS numbers will show up, all of them quite expensive, about 100 EUR/month.

For example a few random ones:

- http://www.mysmsaddress.com/
- http://www.mobifi.com/
- https://www.2-waysms.com/
- http://www.lleida.net/en/

See also [Can anyone recommend any good UK based SMS gateways for sending and receiving SMS using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901505/can-anyone-recommend-any-good-uk-based-sms-gateways-for-sending-and-receiving-sms)